# uploading files in single page applications

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

Currently I am building a single page application in ES6 + PHP and having a few problems with ajax calls. I can't find any example of file uploads via the fetch API and honestly I have no clue if ajax calls are supposed to look like this because of how to read the data in PHP.

Something like this should send a form to the backend.
This is what I got so far, but it doesn't work and can't think of a clean solution :(

JS:

```
const headers = new Headers({
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
});

class User{
    constructor(){
        this._ajaxData = {};
    }

    /**
     * @param {object} curObj
     * @param {int} curObj.ID
     * @param {HTMLElement} curObj.InputDate
     * @param {HTMLElement} curObj.Username
     * @param {HTMLElement} curObj.UploadFile = <input type='file'>
     */
    collectInputData(curObj){
        this._ajaxData = {
            UserID: curObj.ID,
            ChangeDate: curObj.InputDate.value,
            Username: curObj.Username.value,
            SomeFile: curObj.UploadFile
        };
    }

    doAjax(){
        let _ajaxData = this._ajaxData;
        let request = new Request("ajax/saveUser.php", {
            method : "POST",
            headers: headers,
            body   : JSON.stringify(_ajaxData)
        });

        fetch(request).then(function (res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$PDO = \DBCon::getInstance();

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$PDO->beginTransaction();

$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]

$User = new \User();
$User->setUserID($data->UserID);
$User->setChangeDate($data->ChangeDate);
$User->setUsername($data->Username);
/**
 * to use like with $_FILES["fileToUpload"]
 * 
 * @param array $data->SomeFile
 */
$User->setUploadFiles($data->SomeFile);


$User->save();
try{
    $PDO->commit();
    echo true;
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can simplify your FETCH statement a little bit. One of the nice things about fetch is that it will try to apply the correct content type for you.Since you are trying to upload a file as well you will need to pass your `_ajaxData` as a FormData() object. Also you don't need the headers unless you are passing some custom headers or want to define the content-type yourself. Here is an example fetch statement to upload some data.

```
let _ajaxData = new FormData();
_ajaxData.append("UserID", curObj.ID);
_ajaxData.append("ChangeDate", curObj.InputDate.value);
_ajaxData.append("Username", curObj.Username.value);
_ajaxData.append("SomeFile", document.getElementById("fileInputId").files[0]) 

let saveUser = fetch("ajax/saveUser.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: _ajaxData
});

saveUser.then(result => {
    //do something with the result
}).catch(err => {
   //Handle error
});
```

Or even better use async/await

```
const saveUser = async (_ajaxData) => {
    let results = await fetch("ajax/saveUser.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: _ajaxData
    });
    if(results.ok){
        let json = await results.json();
        return json;
    }
    throw new Error('There was an error saving the user')
}
```